# Pandas DataFrame resampling on a depth/length column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, resample

I have some depth-based geological data in pandas data frames, organised by drill hole name, depth from, and depth to, like this:

|  | DDH_name | From_ft | To_ft | ALT1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A-7CD5 | 0.0 | 90.0 | 20 |
| 1 | A-7CD5 | 90.0 | 110.0 | 70 |
| 3 | A-7CD5 | 110.0 | 150.0 | 7 |

I also have another dataframe with more detailed data, on 1ft intervals.

I need a faster way of resampling the "coarse" data (in this case, the 'ALT1' field) into the "fine" data frame, so that the data that exists in the first row of the coarse dataframe that goes from 0ft to 90ft gets painted over the first 90 rows of the fine dataframe when merging. The field looks numerical but is actually a discrete label, so I can't use any interpolation.

Here's the code I have that does the merging at present:

```
df['ALT1'] = ''

for i in df.index:
    w = df['DDH_name'].iloc[i]
    d = df['From_ft'].iloc[i]
    try:
        df['ALT1'][i] = df_alter[df_alter['DDH_name']==w][df_alter['From_ft']<=d][df_alter['To_ft']>d]['ALT1'].values[0]
    except:
        pass
```

This works and produces the desired result, but seems inefficient and takes a long time (up to 30 seconds if the "fine" dataframe has ~100k rows). Is there a better way to merge and resample from coarse intervals to fine ones?

**EDIT:**
Expected final dataframe should look like this (taken just before and after the change in ALT1 value at 90ft):

|  | DDH_name | From_ft | To_ft | ALT1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 85 | A-7CD5 | 85.0 | 86.0 | 20 |
| 86 | A-7CD5 | 86.0 | 87.0 | 20 |
| 87 | A-7CD5 | 87.0 | 88.0 | 20 |
| 88 | A-7CD5 | 88.0 | 89.0 | 20 |
| 89 | A-7CD5 | 89.0 | 90.0 | 20 |
| 90 | A-7CD5 | 90.0 | 91.0 | 70 |
| 91 | A-7CD5 | 91.0 | 92.0 | 70 |
| 92 | A-7CD5 | 92.0 | 93.0 | 70 |
| 93 | A-7CD5 | 93.0 | 94.0 | 70 |
| 94 | A-7CD5 | 94.0 | 95.0 | 70 |
| 95 | A-7CD5 | 95.0 | 96.0 | 70 |
| 96 | A-7CD5 | 96.0 | 97.0 | 70 |

Comment: There's definitely a better and quicker way to do this, but it's hard to help without a [mcve]. Mind posting a sample of the second df, and the expected output ?

Comment: kindly add an expected output dataframe

Comment: you should also include the `fine` dataframe

Comment: Thanks team, have included the expected output now. The "fine" data frame is just the hole name and the depths at 1ft intervals and some chemical composition data, however only the hole name and depths are shown, because that's all that is common between data frames